# Flatstrap for Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get Flatstrap working with Bootstrap 3 but i can't, the link they provide at the website http://flatstrap.org/ does not contain the flat.css and i cannot get it to work anyways. Can someone tell me how to put things together to get the desired flat design ?

Comment: I think you can use the Bootstrap files inside the dist folder.

Comment: did you ever get a working answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the files her :

1. Go to the download page of [Flatstrap](http://flatstrap.org/download.html) ( you have option to download for bootstrap 2 or 3).
2. After downloading the desired files, unzipe the downloaded folder you will find a **dist folder** contains a **css folder**, inside it you will find your files.
3. The Flatstrap files called ( bootstrap.css ) like the original bootstrap files, because they modify it from the beginning so just use them directly, there is no need for any other external sheet files.

hope this help you.

Comment: Well... i tried that but i just get the original bootstrap style and not the flat one ? any ideas ?

Comment: they look exactly the same as bootstrap 3

Comment: The method that they specify to work with Flatstrap as i said, you start your project normal and use the .css included in the dist folder

Comment: that is what i am really doing idk why i just keep getting the normal bootstrap 3 flat theme not the flatstrap one.

Comment: even if you inspect the style sheet for the main site Flatstrap you will find that they use the files in the dist folder, sorry i tried to help but something wrong with the master file that they put for downloading in gitHub also.

Comment: Having the same issue. The dist folder contains the standard bootstrap files for Bootstrap3.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I use their files and its the same as standard bootstrap? useless?

Answer (score 0):

just download the [bootstrap.css from their site](http://flatstrap.org/assets/css/bootstrap.css), thats the flattened version.

So I renamed my flatstrap, and stuck it in the dist folder of normal bootstrap. And referenced that.

Comment: That style is for Bootstrap 2.